# Java null constructor

Tags: java, null

So I have two classes  called songs and albums, here they are:

```
    public class Songs {
    private String title;
    private Double duration;

    public Songs(String title, Double duration) {
        this.title = title;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public Songs(){}


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }



    public Double getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }


    public static Songs addSong(String title, Double duration){
        return new Songs(title,duration);

    }
}



    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Albums {
    private ArrayList<Songs> albums;
    private String name;
    private String title;

    public Albums(String name, String title) {
        this.albums = new ArrayList<>();
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public boolean addSong(Songs songs){
        if(findSong(songs.getTitle())==null){
            this.albums.add(songs);
            return true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Song alredy exist!");
            return false;
        }

    }

      private Songs findSong(String songName){
        for(int i=0;i<this.albums.size();i++){
            Songs currentSong = this.albums.get(i);
            if(currentSong.equals(songName)){
                return currentSong;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is the main, maybe my logic is not right, if I'm missing something please tell me:

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Albums albums = new Albums("Alexandru", "Doi dsadcopii");
        Songs songs = new Songs("Patrascu",4.44);
        songs.addSong("Dorin",11.11);
        albums.addSong(songs);

        songs.addSong("Dorin",11.11);
        albums.addSong(songs);


        songs.addSong("Dorinsads",11.11);
        albums.addSong(songs);


        songs.addSong("Dorisadsan",11.11);
        albums.addSong(songs);



        System.out.println(songs.getTitle());

        albums.addSong(songs);

        albums.printSongs();
    }
}
```

Why I'm getting the same value ? why those values from the .addSong where not added in the list ? This is my code to print the list:

```
    public void  printSongs() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.albums.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + 1 + "-->" + this.albums.get(i).getTitle() + "--->" + this.albums.get(i).getDuration());
    }

}
```

For sure I'm missing something but I dont know exactly where, any ideas how to fix this ? Thanks! :D
The problem is when I'm using the .printSongs() method it prints the first value

Comment: `addSong` doesn't add a `Songs`, it only creates a new object, and you just ignore it.

Comment: words are important. Change to singular Song and Album. Then thing about multiply (Album has many Song) ... so album.add(Song) etc

Comment: Since addSong creates a new object, which is not saved anywhere, your 'songs' variable remains unchanged and you are basically adding the same object 5 times.

Comment: What does the term "null constructor" in your title have to do with your question?

Answer (score 2):

From your class Songs:

```
public static Songs addSong(String title, Double duration){
    return new Songs(title,duration);
}
```

This is just returning a new Song, it is not adding it to the internal List.

You can just add them to the album directly, like

```
Albums albums = new Albums("Alexandru", "Doi dsadcopii");
albums.addSong(new Songs("Patrascu",4.44));
albums.addSong(new Songs("Dorin",11.11));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Song#addSong` method is plain wrong. You are creating new `Sound` objects there. In fact you don't need to do that. Remove that method and use it like this

```
Albums albums = new Albums("Alexandru", "Doi dsadcopii");
albums.addSong(new Songs("Patrascu",4.44));
albums.addSong(new Songs("Dorin",11.11));
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by

```java
songs.addSong("Dorin",11.11);
```

, you meant

```java
Songs.addSong("Dorin",11.11);
```

. This is happening because you are not reassigning songs reference. Replace every statement

```java
songs.addSong("Dorin",11.11);
```

with

```java
songs=Songs.addSong("Dorin",11.11);
```

and it will work. 
Further observation is that your logic in 'findSong()' for equality will always yield false.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use modified below Main class.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Albums albums = new Albums("Alexandru", "Doi dsadcopii");
        Songs songs = new Songs();
        songs=songs.addSong("Patrascu",4.44);
        albums.addSong(songs);
        songs=songs.addSong("Dorin",11.11);
        albums.addSong(songs);

        songs=songs.addSong("Dorin",11.11);
        albums.addSong(songs);



        songs=songs.addSong("Dorinsads",11.11);
        albums.addSong(songs);


        songs=songs.addSong("Dorisadsan",11.11);
        albums.addSong(songs);

        System.out.println(songs.getTitle());

        albums.addSong(songs);

        albums.printSongs();
    }
}
```